# total drinks per day column

Tags: mysql, aggregate, count

Attempting to select a table with a column where the customers total drinks ordered per day are calculated by the odate and drink number.
EG.
Claude orders 10 drinks total on the 2020-1-12

```
drinker | odate      | total_drinks
Claude  | 2020-01-12 | 10 
Claude  | 2020-01-15 | 3
```

How do i condense my current statement

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to the forum! **Please, please** always include your version of MySQL when asking your questions - it can make a huge difference to potential answers! Also, please provide your table structures as DDL and your data as DML - it makes life much easier for those trying to assist you - help us to help you!

Comment: This looks like a homework question - please specify if this is the case. We're always willing to point learners to the right resources to read, instead of "just" giving them the answer.

Comment: You're looking for `group by`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unclear.

What does `drink_no` signify?
You should not try to maintain a "running count" of how many drinks a person has consumed on a given day.  Instead, simply store that they *have* consumed another drink and let your queries do the "adding up":

```
select 
  drinker
, odate
, count( odate ) total 
from table1
group by drinker, odate
order by drinker, odate ; 

+---------+------------+-------+
| drinker | odate      | total | 
+---------+------------+-------+
| Claude  | 2020-01-12 |     4 | 
| Claude  | 2020-01-15 |     2 | 
| Claude  | 2020-01-19 |     1 | 
| Claude  | 2020-04-04 |     1 | 
| Claude  | 2020-04-05 |     1 | 
| Claude  | 2020-04-12 |     1 | 
| Claude  | 2020-04-15 |     1 | 
| Claude  | 2020-04-16 |     1 | 
| Claude  | 2020-04-17 |     1 | 
| Claude  | 2020-04-18 |     1 | 
| Claude  | 2020-04-19 |     1 | 
| Claude  | 2020-04-20 |     1 | 
+---------+------------+-------+
```

Also, please tell me that odate is an actual **Date** Data Type.

*Never* store Date values in *anything else*.  Doing so will make date manipulation far, *far* more difficult and, potentially, much slower.

Comment: The original tables were given for me to work off. Drink number is the total drinks the drinker orders in the given transaction not a running count, I need to add the drink_no that occur on the same date

Comment: find the drinker, order date and total number of drinks
ordered by each drinker in a same day.

Comment: @xanthon23: In that case, replace "count()" by "sum()".

Comment: SUM(odate) doesn't work

Comment: Its `sum(drink_no)`. You want to sum the drinks.